# Generating multiple ROC curves in Weka GUI

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm using the Weka 3.6 GUI to compare the performance of a group of supervised learning algorithms on a dataset. I'm generating separate ROC curves for each learning algorithm. My problem is: is there a way in Weka to generate all ROC curves for all algorithms on the same set of scales (which would make for easier comparison)? If not, what could I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my experience tells me- No. You can view ROC of one classifier at a time not ROCs of all classifiers in one place. However, to compare, you can take the ROC value from the classifier tab and compare the values (closer to 1 means good classifier).

Answer (score 9):

This *is* possible. You need to use the `KnowledgeFlow` GUI though instead of the `Experimenter`.

In KnowledgeFlow you can load your dataset and perform different algorithms on it. The result of each algorithm can then be combined into the same `Model PerformanceChart` resulting in a plot which combines the multiple ROC curves. Detailed steps can be found in section 4.2 in [this guide](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/KnowledgeFlowTutorial-3-5-8.pdf?download).

Comment: This link is working (for now): http://software.ucv.ro/~eganea/AIR/KnowledgeFlowTutorial-3-5-8.pdf

Comment: @Vladtn I've tried your nice tutorial on multiple training set and one test set, unfortunately, I did not get multiple curves!